# Chrome Extension: Waiting For Element to Load (async js)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I have a Chrome extension, and I want to wait until an element is loaded before injecting content into the page.

I'm trying to inject a button:

```
myButton = document.createElement('button');
myButton.class = 'mybutton';
document.querySelector('.element_id').appendChild(myButton)
```

I have this at the top of my content script. It used to work just fine, but then it stopped working. The error that was displayed was:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

In order to wait for the element with class id `.element_id` to load, I tried to use a MutationObserver

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return

        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            if (mutation.addedNodes[i].parentNode == document.querySelector('#outer-container')) {

                myButton = document.createElement('button');
                myButton.class = 'mybutton';
                document.querySelector('.element_id').appendChild(myButton)
        }
            var node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
        }
    })
})

observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true
    , subtree: true
    , attributes: false
    , characterData: false
})
```

When I used the mutation observer, the page would load an outer div element called `outer-container`, and there was no way for me to directly compare the class `.element_id`. The class `.element_id` is nested a number of layers into the outer div.

HOWEVER, the above did not work, and I still received the null property error.

Is there a better way to wait for some element to be loaded (which is loaded async), before injecting?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add [`childList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [`subtree`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) property when observing changes.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            if (mutation.addedNodes[i].classList.contains("element_id")) {
                // Your logic here
            }
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the properties. I had `childList`, but it still fails :(

Comment: @confused, could you please try my code? I have verified and I believe it should work.

Comment: @HaibaraAi See my answer.

Comment: Also, don't forget `subtree: true`.

Answer (score 1):

An insertion into DOM may have the element in question deeper in the added node.

For example, this can be inserted into the DOM:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element_id">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

In that case, the added node list will only contain the `.container` node.

The mutation will not list everything added, it's your responsibility to recursively dig into the added fragment looking through added nodes.

Using [`mutation-summary` library](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) may help you avoid such headaches.

```
var observer = new MutationSummary({
  rootNode: document.body,
  callback: function(summaries) {
    summaries.forEach(function(summary) {
      summary.added.forEach(function(idElement) {
        /* ... */
        idElement.appendChild(myButton);
      });
    });
  },
  queries: [{element: ".element_id"}]
});
```

If you don't want to use a library, you can try calling `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` on `addedNodes[i]`.