getElementById is returning null even though the document has completed loading
I'm creating a chrome plugin that involves manipulating DOM elements. The code in my content.js file is run in a function called setup and I call this function in the following way:
if (document.readyState === "complete")
    setup();
else
    document.addEventListener("readystatechange", setup);

when I run console.log(document.readyState) in the setup function I'm seeing complete in DevTools, however when I try to access a particular element from within setup using the getElementById() method it's returning null.
I've tried various methods to ensure the page is completely loaded before calling setup but I've had no luck. When I call getElementById() from the console in DevTools I'm getting the result I expect.
This is only happening on one particular site, is there anything else I can try or any potential quirks of a website that might be causing this kind of behaviour. The element i'm trying to access isn't part of an iframe either.

Are you sure the element you want is in the document's HTML? If it's created dynamically by JavaScript, it won't be there yet when the document is ready.

If that's the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759715/chrome-extension-waiting-for-element-to-load-async-js

I wouldn't be sure about that, I know it isn't part of an iframe and I know it's there when I call from the DevTools console. If that is the case here, would there be a way to work around that and wait for this specific element to be ready? Edit: Just seen your second comment, thank you so much for a quick reply, I'll have a read through but it looks from the first line like exactly what I need.

Where does your code call document.getElementById?

Brilliant, MutationObservers to the rescue! thank you so much again for such a quick response!
